# Slicing function on <for> loop

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, slice

I am a beginner coder, using python 3.7.1 on a windows 10 with Visual Code Studio.

As exercise I am trying to **scrape** from a webpage some data organized by a table.

Now, I want to extract some information only, which is nested into the
`<td valign="top" style="width:25%;">Parte edibile, %</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight:bold;">75</td>` values. As delimiter here I have `<td> ... </td>`

I did try many way to get only the first and second   of each row, since the third   is NOT interesting for me, it is just a waste of memory which I don't need.

To do that, I am using a 'for' loop but as I've understood by BeautifulSoup spreadsheet, when it takes a loop, all nested arguments of each row are united in one and therefore if I want slice [0:1] = >> the first and second "string" arguments `<td> </td>`, is not possible.

Here's the simple loop 'for':

`for alim in soup.find_all('td')[0:1]: return alim.text`

Am I correct? Anyone could propose me some smarter solution to solve my question?

Thank you in advance for any advice.
Max

Comment: What form is the data in, a string?

Comment: If you want the first *and* second items, use `soup.find_all('td')[0:2]` instead

Comment: @Artog, yes it is a string.

Comment: @Anwarvic, I have been using your proposal but it doesn't work for my text. That is why I have been posting here, it was strange to me also. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have table with 3+ columns and you are interested only in first two columns.

To extract data from first two columns, you have many possibilities. One is using CSS selectors:

```
data = '''
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:25%;">I. Parte edibile, %</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight:bold;">I. 75</td>
        <td>This doesn't interest me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:25%;">II. Parte edibile, %</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight:bold;">II. 75</td>
        <td>II. This doesn't interest me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:25%;">III. Parte edibile, %</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight:bold;">III. 75</td>
        <td>III. This doesn't interest me</td>
    </tr>
    </table>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for col1, col2 in zip(soup.select('td:nth-of-type(1)'), soup.select('td:nth-of-type(2)')):
    print('{: <25} {}'.format(col1.text, col2.text))
```

Prints:

```
I. Parte edibile, %       I. 75
II. Parte edibile, %      II. 75
III. Parte edibile, %     III. 75
```

---

Or you can use list slicing:

```
rows = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    rows.append([td.text for td in tr.select('td')[0:2]])

for row in rows:
    print('{: <25} {}'.format(*row))
```

---

EDIT: For parsing the page `http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/ComponentiAlimento.aspx?Lan=Ita&foodid=1300_2` you can use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/ComponentiAlimento.aspx?Lan=Ita&foodid=1300_2'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for col1, col2 in zip(soup.select('#tblComponenti > tr.testonormale > td:nth-of-type(1)'), soup.select('#tblComponenti > tr.testonormale > td:nth-of-type(2)')):
    print('{: <70} {}'.format(col1.text, col2.text))
```

Prints:

```
Parte edibile, %                                                       75
Energia, ricalcolata, kJ                                               406
Energia, Ric con fibra, kJ                                             406
Energia, ricalcolata, kcal                                             96
Energia, Ric con fibra, kcal                                           96
Proteine totali, g                                                     16,8
   Proteine animali, g                                                 16,8
   Proteine vegetali, g                                                0,0
Lipidi totali, g                                                       2,6
   Lipidi animali, g                                                   2,6
   Lipidi vegetali, g                                                  0,0
Colesterolo, mg                                                        61
Carboidrati disponibili (MSE), g                                       1,5
   Amido (MSE), g                                                      0,0
   Carboidrati solubili (MSE), g                                       1,5
Fibra alimentare totale, g                                             0,0
Alcol, g                                                               0,0
Acqua, g                                                               76,5
Ferro, mg                                                              2,8
Calcio, mg                                                             148
Sodio, mg                                                              104
Potassio, mg                                                           278
Fosforo, mg                                                            196
Zinco, mg                                                              4,20
Magnesio, mg                                                           22
Rame, mg                                                               1,00
Selenio, µg                                                            37,0
Cloro, mg                                                              130
Iodio, µg                                                              29
Manganese, mg                                                          0,07
Zolfo, mg                                                              150
Vitamina B1, Tiamina, mg                                               0,06
Vitamina B2, Riboflavina, mg                                           0,26
Vitamina C, mg                                                         0
Niacina, mg                                                            14,00
Vitamina B6, mg                                                        0,14
Folati totali, µg                                                      9
Acido pantotenico, mg                                                  0,65
Biotina, µg                                                            6,0
Vitamina B12, µg                                                       0,6
Retinolo equivalente                                                   32
   Retinolo eq. (RE), µg                                               32
   Retinolo, µg                                                        tr
   ß-carotene eq., µg                                                  0,29
Vitamina E (ATE), mg                                                   11,00
Vitamina D, µg                                                         1,30
Acidi grassi saturi totali, g                                          0,00
Somma degli acidi butirrico, caproico, caprilico e caprico, g          0,00
Acido laurico, g                                                       0,14
Acido miristico, g                                                     1,01
Acido palmitico, g                                                     0,13
Acido stearico, g                                                      tr
Acido arachidico, g                                                    0,00
Acido beenico, g                                                       0,40
Acidi grassi monoinsaturi totali, g                                    0,00
Acido miristoleico, g                                                  0,10
Acido palmitoleico, g                                                  0,17
Acido oleico, g                                                        0,01
Acidi eicosenoico, g                                                   0,01
Acido erucico, g                                                       0,85
Acidi grassi polinsaturi totali, g                                     0,01
Acido linoleico, g                                                     0,01
Acido linolenico, g                                                    tr
Acido arachidonico, g                                                  0,27
Acido eicosapentaenoico (EPA), g                                       0,52
Acido decosaesaenoico (DHA), g                                         0,04
Altri acidi grassi polinsaturi, g                                      175
Triptofano, mg                                                         726
Treonina, mg                                                           823
Isoleucina, mg                                                         1330
Leucina, mg                                                            1379
Lisina, mg                                                             349
Metionina, mg                                                          183
Cistina, mg                                                            595
Fenilalanina, mg                                                       425
Tirosina, mg                                                           759
Valina, mg                                                             758
Arginina, mg                                                           675
Istidina, mg                                                           919
Alanina, mg                                                            1764
Acido aspartico, mg                                                    2261
Acido glutammico, mg                                                   722
Glicina, mg                                                            460
Prolina, mg                                                            650
Serina, mg                                                             1,5
Glucosio, g                                                            0,0
Fruttosio, g                                                           0,0
Galattosio, g                                                          0,0
Saccarosio (MSE), g                                                    0,0
Maltosio (MSE), g                                                      0,0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej! I appreciate your help.

Could you please point me also where should I get to deep into learning your solutions? Is it in BeautifulSoup documentation or in Python guide?

Comment: @Massimo I would start at BeautifulSoup's documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ Also it's useful to learn CSS selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp - you can use them not only in BeautifulSoup, but in Javascript etc.

Comment: Your first proposal does it fit also into a "def" function?

Comment: @Massimo Yes, you could make a function that returns list, instead of printing. It depends on your use-case.

Comment: Great and useful advices Andrej, thank you so much. I am going to learn deeply about it.
Have a good August 15th :)

Comment: Sorry Andrej, I have been trying your solutions but both of them print me out the whole text row as follow, sticking all <td> together:
\nParte edibile, %75Some text I don't want to be printed out\n 

While should be printed out only: 
Parte edibile, % 75

What I still don't understand?

Comment: @Massimo I edited my answer. There are lots of nested `<table>`, so I changed a CSS selector a little bit

Comment: great Andrej! you open me a new world. Nesting tables is a hard job to find out, for me at least. Although, what does it mean, where it takes action when you write print('{: <70} {}' ) ?? I cannot understand it.

Answer (score 1):

If the return type is a list you should use `[0:2]` as the final number is non-inclusive (however the return will jump out of the loop) so needs to be changed slightly:

```py
result = []
for alim in soup.find_all('td')[0:2]:
     result.append(alim.text)
return result
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I have been trying also your solution, it appear really like the Python zen way. 
But it doesn't work for me, I still don't know what I didn't understand.

Your solution print out the text but still with those text I don't want and furthermore it is not ordered as per rows sequence.

I see into the text it appear " \n "  at each new text line but NOT in a new row. I hope I did explain clear enough.

Any idea what is wrong to my code?

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to take the first 2 elements:

1) using map function with getattr, I like this way because you are iterating only over the first 2 elements

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html, 'lxml') 
r = soup.find_all('td')
gen_my_soup_text = map(lambda x: getattr(x, 'text'), r)

first_string = next(gen_my_soup_text)
second_string = next(gen_my_soup_text)

print(first_string)
print(second_string)

# output: 
# Parte edibile, %
# 75
```

2) using slicing and map

```
list(map(lambda x: getattr(x, 'text'), r))[:2]
```

3) using list comprehension and slicing

```
[e.text for e in r][:2]
```

to scrape your web page you can try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


req = requests.get('http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Alphabetical.aspx?Lan=Ita')
soup =  BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

# result is the container of the tags of interest.
rows = soup.find_all("tr", attrs = {'class':'testonormale'})
first_second = [[e.text for e in row.find_all('td')][:2] for row in rows]

# output: 
#[['1300', 'ACCIUGHE o ALICI '],
# ['1502', 'ACCIUGHE o ALICI SOTTO SALE'],
# ['1501', "ACCIUGHE o ALICI SOTT'OLIO"],
# ['100205', 'ACETO'],
....
# ['602004', 'ASTICE '],
# ['600009', 'AVENA '],
# ['999692', 'AVOCADO ']]
```

Comment: Thank you rusu_ro1. 

I assume your third solution is the only one with "for" loop, if I did understand correctly, but I did not understand it how does it work. I am nesting the loop into a function "def". 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I finished to try also your second proposal but as well, I got the wrong output. The output has not sliced out the third <td> ....</td>, seems it are all sticked in one row that incluede all <td> ..</td>, in fact does not change anything if I use a slice [0:2] or [0:4 or 5 ..] the output is the same :(

Any idea what could be wrong to my code?

Comment: Can you give me the webpage please

Comment: thank you rusu, I appreciate your help altough Andrej's feedback fit better with my target.